# Theano NanGuardMode kills the network, but no NaN is present in the input

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano, keras

I'm reimplementing the network from the [DeepMask paper](https://github.com/facebookresearch/deepmask) using Keras on top of Theano. Everything looks fine, but after a (completely random) while the loss goes to NaN. I've launched theano using the NaNGuardMode to check whether there are NaN around and it kills the training at the very first batch with the error:

> AssertionError: NaN detected
>
> NanGuardMode found an error in an input of the graph.

The batch sampling is randomized, and it does this with every single batch. I've had the batch generator pickle the batch before feeding it to the training, and I've checked the actual presence of np.nan in the data (which could have happened due to some division by 0 in some normalization, albeit weird). This:

```
res = np.isnan(batch)
res[res==True]
```

always returns and empty list, meaning that no NaN has been found in the data. Doesn't the error risen by the NanGuard imply that the NaN is at the input of my network?

The architecture is fairly simple and starts with a pre-trained VGG-16 obtained from the publicly available implementation in Keras available [here](https://gist.github.com/baraldilorenzo/07d7802847aaad0a35d3).

What can be causing my network to be stopped by the NanGuardMode if not a problem with the input? Beside a couple of layers near the end, the network is identical to the public VGG implementation which is known to work well.

Thank you for any input!

Comment: Big values may be causing nans as well (e.g. `inf/inf`). Which Keras and Theano version are you using? Have you tried updating to a newer version of Theano?

Comment: I'm using the dev version of theano, 
0.9.0dev2.dev-68adb874f1beff4ebfedcc307fa08dc569e68c0f
and keras 1.0.8 (the issue present itself even on a different machine running the same theano but keras 1.0.7)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the nan guard mode was updated recently. Try a 'stable' release of Theano, e.g. 0.8.2. Do you have the same problem with the model that you are building up on?

Comment: I've checked and the problem occurs even when using the standard vgg net I'm building on, so it's either input related or version related. The problem is, I cannot change theano version on the machines I'm working on right now..

Comment: Ok, there is definitely something wrong with the NanGuardMode, it kills the mnist example saying it detects an Inf in the input graph...

Comment: Use a python virtualenv to install a different version of Theano and test if downgrading fixes your problem. No root access required. If it fixes your problem then report a bug on the [theano bug tracker](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Ran into the same problem.